# How to keep code clean when processing unique html structures?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, scrape

I'm writing a service in python that crawls web pages and pulls specific information using BeautifulSoup. I find that the code is becoming really messy as I'm writing specific operations to pull the data.

For example: `htmlObject.strip().split("delimiter")[2].get("data")`

It's hard especially when revisiting this code to figure out what's going on and what the initial html object looks like. What are some ways to improve the maintainability of this part of the code besides extensive documentation?

Edit 1:

Example code using BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body)
teams = soup.find_all("div", class_="team")
for team in teams:
    team_names = team.find_all("div", class_="team-header")[0].find("div").get_text(",", strip=True)
    region, name = tuple(team_names.split(","))
```

Comment: Could you show more code, in particular, what `htmlObject` is? Thanks.

Comment: Put comments in the code. And split it into multiple statements so you can give meaningful names to the sub-expressions.

Comment: @alecxe Added an edit

Comment: In addition to Barmar comments. Check that all your 'find' and 'get' calls return what you expect (not None and the correct length) with an assert or 'if' test and then print or log soup.prettify(). Also, if you inserted lots of print commands when writing the  parser, keep them around, don't delete them when you are done.